# Ajax Post method fails to retrieve data while GET does

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

my problem is pretty straight-forward I have a PHP script that returns data when it receives the request from Ajax HTTP GET or POST method, problem is, the GET method works and returns data, while the POST method doesn't. i dont want to  use the GET method cause it comes along with a 304 FORBIDDEN ACCESS error on my browser console, though data is actually received.

this is my php script:

```
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
        //print_r $_POST;
        $alt_action = $_POST["action"];
    switch($alt_action){

        case 'get_post':
        getAjaxPost($user_id,"");
        break;
        case 'get_grouplings':
        getGrouplings($user_id);
        break;

        case 'get_new':
        getAjaxPost($user_id,"normal");

        break;

        case 'get_featured':
        getFeaturedGroup();
        break;

        default:

        return false;
        break;


    }   
}
```

and this is my ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'inc/modules/getters.php?nocache=',
    type: 'POST',
    data: "action=get_new",
    success: function (data) {
    alert(data);
      //$('#posts').append(data);

    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
```

Comment: data: "action=get_new",wrong .please change data: {action:get_new}, and also in psot no need to pass data in url

Comment: change to data: {action :"get_new"}

Comment: Why did you set `contentType` and `processData` to `false`? Remove them,  let them have their default values.

Comment: @Niladri jquery returns the data to a key=value pair if you speific data as an object, thats not it

Comment: @RajdeepPaul that solved the issue thanks

Comment: @Maxwell data is the property of the ajax call not an object here